# Is a metric space with unique balls infinite/uncountable?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a non-empty metric space with the following property: if $B(x,r) = B(y,s)$, then $x=y$ and $r=s$, where $B(x,r)$ is the closed ball with center $x$ and radius $r$. Must $M$ be infinite? In fact, must $M$ be uncountable?

Comment: If there is even one $x$ such that the balls $B(x,r)$ for $r=1,2,3,\dots$ are all distinct, then $M$ must be infinite. On the other hand, the space of rational numbers with the usual metric has your property but is countable.

Comment: @bof That should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Uncountable, no.** The space of rational numbers with the usual metric has your property but is countable.

**Infinite, yes.** If $B(x,1),B(x,2),B(x,3),\dots$ are all different then $M$ must be infinite, since for each $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a point $y_n$ such that $d(x,y_n)\in(n,n+1]$.

Comment: What if the radius is irrational? Then, does the space of rational numbers still have the property?

Comment: Yes. For instance, if $r,s\in\mathbb R$, $0\lt r\lt s$, then $\mathbb Q\cap(-r,r)$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb Q\cap(-s,s)$, because there are rational numbers between $r$ and $s$; it does not matter if $r$ and $s$ are rational or irrational.